# Cannot open MS Project file on Livelink via Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project, livelink

I am building a tool that allows a user to open and edit an MS Project file that I am going to be storing on a Livelink site.  I've done this before where I edit an excel file in Livelink and taking the WebDav link and converting it to a file location:
WebDav Link - http://livelink.com/csdav/nodes/...
File Location - \livelink.com\csdav\nodes...

I am doing the same exact thing for the Project file, but cannot open it using the file location.  Anyway around this?

Code:

```
    Set appProj = CreateObject("Msproject.Application")
    appProj.ScreenUpdating = False
    appProj.FileOpen proj_file 'proj_file is the file location
    appProj.Visible = True
    Set aProj = appProj.ActiveProject
    aProj.Activate
```

Comment: Where is this code running? Is it in Excel--is that why the Excel tags are included?

Comment: @RachelHettinger yes, it is running in Excel

Comment: What is the error message? What happens if you manually open that project file using that formatting "file location" within MS Project natively?

Comment: The error message is a Run-time error 1004 that says "Project cannot open the file."  I can manually open it in MS Project as long as I sign into the Livelink site.

Comment: Sounds like MS Project needs you to sign into Livelink first. Perhaps in Excel you are already signed in before opening Excel files through Livelink.